# runtime error 424 "Object Required" during finding specific name in the range

Tags: excel, vba

below script I'm running, but getting "runtime error", help needed, what is wrong?

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NameToFind As Variant
Dim FindRes As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Call Find_files ' Show all files in directory in range A18:A109
Set NameToFind = sh.Range("N5") 'name stored in cell N5
Set FindRes = sh.Range("A18:A109").Find(What:=NameToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
If FindRes Is Empty Then '---<Error is here...
   Debug.Print "no match found to " & sh.Range("N5").Value
Else
   Debug.Print "match found"
End If
```

Comment: `If FindRes Is Nothing Then`

Comment: `Call` is from QuickBasic for MS-Dos. It calls assembler functions with a different calling convention to Basic. In Windows you cannot call assembler functions and exists for porting MS-Dos code to Windows code. It is highly unlikely that you are porting MS-Dos code.

Comment: i'm using other sub Find_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if FindRes is `Nothing`, not `Empty`.

```vb
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NameToFind As Variant
Dim FindRes As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Call Find_files ' Show all files in directory in range A18:A109
Set NameToFind = sh.Range("N5") 'name stored in cell N5
Set FindRes = sh.Range("A18:A109").Find(What:=NameToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
If FindRes Is Nothing Then 
   Debug.Print "no match found to " & sh.Range("N5").Value
Else
   Debug.Print "match found"
End If
```

Comment: thank you very much, changed "Empty" to "Nothing", working, but always showed that "no match" even file name contain word stored in Range("N5")

Comment: Find will look for an exact match unless you tell it otherwise. What are you actually trying to find?

Comment: I've tried to find a specified word within range A18:A109 ,stored in "N5"